# Group objects in an array by Id - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object array that has two fields id, and the type of action permission

```
const array=[
{view: false, id: 1},
{create: false, id: 1},
{read: false, id: 1},
{update: false, id: 1},
{delete: false, id: 1},
{view: false, id: 2},
{create: false, id: 2},
{read: false, id: 2},
{update: false, id: 2},
{delete: false, id: 2},
]
```

I want to convert this in to the following array:

```
const permissions=[
{
id: 1,
view: false,
read: false,
create: false,
delete:false,
update:false
},
{
id: 2,
view: false,
read: false,
create: false,
delete:false,
update:false
}
]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over the array using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) while updating a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) where the `id` is the `key` and its resulting object is the `value`.

In the end, you would have the grouped objects per `id` as the `values` in this map:

```js
const array = [
  {view: false, id: 1},
  {create: false, id: 1},
  {read: false, id: 1},
  {update: false, id: 1},
  {delete: false, id: 1},
  {view: false, id: 2},
  {create: false, id: 2},
  {read: false, id: 2},
  {update: false, id: 2},
  {delete: false, id: 2},
];

const res = [...
  array.reduce((map, { id, ...elem }) =>
    map.set(id, { ...(map.get(id) || { id }), ...elem })
  , new Map)
  .values()
];

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example which also uses `array.reduce` but plain object instead of javascript `Map` object. The solution is also not minified.

```
const data = [
    { view: false, id: 1 },
    { create: false, id: 1 },
    { read: false, id: 1 },
    { update: false, id: 1 },
    { delete: false, id: 1 },
    { view: false, id: 2 },
    { create: false, id: 2 },
    { read: false, id: 2 },
    { update: false, id: 2 },
    { delete: false, id: 2 },
]

const merged = data.reduce((prev, current) => {

    // get the id.
    // make it to string as we use it as key and not index!
    const id = '' + current.id

    // create object if it does not already exist:
    if (!prev[id]) {
        prev[id] = {}
    }


    // store the given data, merge it with already
    // existing data under the id
    prev[id] = {
        ...prev[id],
        ...current
    }

    // return the results.
    return prev

}, {})

// now that we have merged togehter the objects, 
// extract them and push em together to an array:

const results = Object.keys(merged).map(k => merged[k])

console.log('results', results)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example, maybe not as elegant as using reduce, but a simple version using for of and a map data type.

```js
const array = [{
  view: false,
  id: 1
}, {
  create: false,
  id: 1
}, {
  read: false,
  id: 1
}, {
  update: true,
  id: 1
}, {
  delete: false,
  id: 1
}, {
  view: false,
  id: 1
}, {
  create: false,
  id: 1
}, {
  read: false,
  id: 1
}, {
  update: false,
  id: 1
}, {
  delete: false,
  id: 1
}]

const perm = {}
for(let el of array){
    const {id} = el
  perm[id] = perm[id] ? {...perm[id], "id": id} : {"id": id}
  for(let key in el){
    if(key === 'id'){
        continue
    }
    perm[id] = {...perm[id], [key]: el[key]}
  }
}

console.log("Permissions Map:", perm)

const permissionsArray = Object.values(perm)
console.log("Permissions Array:",permissionsArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for some exercise; `.reduce()` and `Object.assign()` can be handy. The thing is, the resulting array will be a sparse one with object items occupying the indices with the corresponding `id` values.

```js
var a = [ {view: false, id: 1}
        , {create: false, id: 1}
        , {read: true, id: 1}
        , {update: false, id: 1}
        , {delete: false, id: 1}
        , {view: false, id: 2}
        , {create: false, id: 2}
        , {read: false, id: 2}
        , {update: true, id: 2}
        , {delete: false, id: 2}
        ],
    g = a.reduce((c,o) => ( c[o.id] = c[o.id] ? Object.assign(c[o.id],o)
                                              : o
                          , c
                          ),[]);

console.log(g);
```

Now this is only a half measure. If you deal with the sparse arrays then you should make sure that the proper and efficient way to traverse them later on is to use a `for in` loop or `Object.keys()`. Otherwise you may waste huge amounts of time checking the holes if the `id`s are very sparse. i.e. One `id` being 1 and the next one being 10000000. Besides, the `.length` property will also include the unused indices. Not ideal.

Then you may think why exactly we need an array to group them under if we will end up with a sparse array? So one good idea would be to group them under another object. This might turn out to be a better abstraction as per your logic. So just do like;

```
g = a.reduce((c,o) => ( c[o.id] = c[o.id] ? Object.assign(c[o.id],o)
                                          : o
                      , c
                      ),{});
```